# Does LD_PRELOAD work on all flavors of unix/linux?

Tags: c++, linux, unix, ubuntu, ld-preload

I wrote a simple LD_PRELOAD module, compiled on Ubuntu server. Will this preload work on other systems like Solaris, FreeBSD, CentOS and etc. Are there any special issues on some of the OSes?

Comment: you mean the resulting binary? No it won't. It's Linux-specific.

Comment: @H2CO3, so, i cant use Ubuntu-compiled LD_PRELOAD on unix systems like Freebsd? What i should do? Maybe recompile on Freebsd?

Comment: Yes, exactly. If the platform you're targeting is not ABI-compatible with Linux (FreeBSD is not, AFAIK), then you have to recompile.

Comment: @H2CO3 Thanks for your answer, can you tell me, on which OS i should compile LD_PRELOAD to work on most unix/linux systems? Thanks!

Comment: @H2CO3 there's no reason it would be Linux-specific

Comment: @Celada Oh yes there is. I didn't say there's no LD_PRELOAD on other Unices, but I said they're not ABI-compatible.

Comment: @Robert: on the same system you insist running the binary on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `LD_PRELOAD` mechanism works across all ELF systems (Linux, Solaris, etc...).

In theory the same library could be usable on different operating systems if the architecture is a match (e.g. an i386 library won't work on Solaris SPARC) but there are many pitfalls. For example, many data structures provided by the C library have different sizes and member arrangements and they will be incompatible between operating systems even if the architecture is the same.

If you are very careful about what functions you call in your `LD_PRELOAD` library then you may be able to create a library that is compatible between operating systems. You will definitely need to test it.

Comment: Correction: you mean "all" (most?) dynamically linked ELF systems. LD_PRELOAD definitely does not work on static-linked ELF systems.

Comment: Good point, @R.. I wonder though if there (still) exist any systems that support ELF but not dynamic linking!